# MySQL join query for multiple matching conditions

Tags: mysql

First off, I apologise for the vague title.. I will update it to better reflect my question if anyone has a suggestion, but for not I do not know how to categorise this topic:

I have a few tables storing information for some device. The tables are organised as shown below. The dev_prop table has some properties which are also components. Components have properties stored in the comp_prop table on the right. Other device properties like "color" do not have any more properties associated with them, just a value.

```
device       dev_prop                      comp_prop

name  id     name   value   id  dev_id    name   value  id  dp_id

dv1   1      comp1  aaa     1    1        height 30cm   1    1
dv2   2      comp2  bbb     2    1        height 20cm   2    2
dv3   3      color  red     3    1        height 20cm   3    4
             comp1  ccc     4    2        weight 300g   4    2
             comp2  aaa     5    2        weight 250g   5    4
             color  blue    6    2        weight 99g    6    1
             color  pink    7    3
```

I want to query the database to select all components that have height 20cm, but I also want to get their weight properties in a separate row. All rows I retrieve should have one comp_prop.value, and only one.

In the sample data above, this would apply to dev_props with id's 2 and 4, because these have heights of 20cm. I would like 4 rows return then, two for their heights, and other two for their weights.

For example, I would like to retrieve rows like this:

```
select device.name, dev_prop.name, dev_prop.value, dev_prop.id,
comp_prop.name, comp_prop.value from comp_prop
inner join dev_prop on comp_prop.dp_id=dev_prop.id and ......

device | dev_prop.name | dev_prop.value | dev_prop.id | comp_prop.name | comp_prop.value 

dv1      comp2           bbb              2             height            20cm  
dv1      comp2           bbb              2             weight            300g
dv2      comp1           ccc              4             height            20cm
dv2      comp1           ccc              4             weight            250g
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't put the color in comp_prop? It would make for a much cleaner schema. After all, what's really the difference between 'color' and 'weight'? Of course we have no idea what the data is really about, so we can't really know, but I thought it was weird. As for your question, I think it might be quite hard to get additional results, based on the results of a first query, all in one query. I think you get into sub-query territory here, apart from having to join things.

Comment: Thanks KIKO software. The schema is not something I am able to change, but for argument sake assume the device has internal components that themselves have differing height, and weight and the colour of a device is not associated with a particular component, rather the enclosure of the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you considered nesting the query? First here's the nest:

```
SELECT dp_id FROM comp_prop WHERE height = '20cm'
```

Which would give you the dp_id of all items with certain attribute, which can be shoved into conditional like so:

```
SELECT * FROM comp_prop WHERE dp_id IN (...)
```

And then just join the other three tables together